# wix, how to add a string to custom path

Tags: wix

I am very new to the WiX toolset. I have to create an installer with two requirements:

1. Install the program to the default path. This works well.
2. User can choose a path. This works well but I have to always add the name of the directory as a string I gave to `"WIXUI_INSTALLDIR"`.

How can I add the directory name automatically?

Here is a code sample:

```
<Directory Id="COMNET" Name="COMNET">
   <Directory Id="DICSHS_1" Name="DICSHS">
      <Component Id="DICSHS.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="2E3EED9D-369D-41E4-A213-0479912E4A40">
         <File Id="DICSHS.EXE" Name="DicsHs.exe" Source="C:\Wix_Tests\program files\COMNET\DICSHS\DicsHs.exe">
            <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="DicsHs" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="yes" Icon="DesktopIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
            <Shortcut Id="ExeShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="DicsHs" Advertise="yes" Icon="StartMenuIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
         </File>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="SHOWERROR.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="14B32974-B447-4A8B-973D-C96D80251BE8">
         <File Id="SHOWERROR.EXE" Name="ShowError.exe" Source="C:\Wix_Tests\program files\COMNET\DICSHS\ShowError.exe" />
      </Component>
```

Here I use the directory COMNET in WIXUI_INSTALLDIR:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="COMNET" /> 
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

But when the user chooses a path, I have to add always the string COMNET on the end of the custom path. This is this is my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add one more root Directory before the COMNET and set that ID to WIXUI_INSTALLDIR.

Example:

```
<Directory Id=" DIR_ROOT" Name="Sample">
   <Directory Id="COMNET" Name="COMNET">

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="DIR_ROOT” />
```